# H2 with heavy data + dbcp2 2.1.0 creating deadlock at borrowObject

Tags: java, caching, connection-pooling, h2, apache-commons-dbcp

I have H2 database with cache increased to 1.5GB for some heavy data loading.
Currently using dbcp2 2.1.0 version.
I have not enabled dbcp2 statement pooling yet.
What I have observed is , when I reduce down the data loaded in H2, dbcp2 works fine.When I load all the heavy data in H2, dbcp2 getting deadlocked.
I am using H2 for FitNesse.
Can anyone help me to identify if its the issue with H2 or with dbcp2 pool?

See the ThreadDump below:

```
"Thread-1" prio=6 tid=0x00000000120b0800 nid=0x3f04 waiting on condition [0x000000001417d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000005cd4f1a08> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:583)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:442)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource$PaGetConnection.run(BasicDataSource.java:2409)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource$PaGetConnection.run(BasicDataSource.java:2405)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1524)
```

Comment: Thanks @pzaenger for the edit.

Comment: any suggestions on how to solve the same, we are using dbcp2 2.6 and are encountering the same issues